# jquery - select an option based on data

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select a particular option based on what I get from a query;

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number > option[value=' + response.Adjunct_Title_Number + ']').attr('selected','selected');
```

I simply get nothing selected.  I know that the value of 58 is being inserted into the statement.

Comment: Is this script located in a separate file?

Comment: Separate from what? It's inline script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number').val(response.Adjunct_Title_Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't set a select box by setting `selected` on the options, but by setting the value of the select box with [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number').val(response.Adjunct_Title_Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number option').filter(function() {
    return this.value == response.Adjunct_Title_Number;
}).prop('selected','true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the value with quotes:

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number > option[value="' + response.Adjunct_Title_Number + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if `$('#Adjunct_Title_Number > option[value=' + response.Adjunct_Title_Number + ']')` is a defined item (not empty object).

Next you should on older jQuery to remove attribute selected from other items:

```
$('#Adjunct_Title_Number option').removeAttr('selected').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).value == response.Adjunct_Title_Number) })
.attr('selected','selected');
```